# What is the meaning Partitioned Signatures?

Tags: cr.crypto-security

Context: Boneh & Boyen devised a transformation for these class of signatures which increases the security to stronger notion of unforgeability.

It would be nice if it is an example. Thanks!

Reference Paper:  [Strongly Unforgeable Signature based on CDH assumption](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.78.7439&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Could you link to that reference and provide more context?

Comment: Hi bala, I have merged your ids. I would suggest that you register an account so you will not create new ids unintentionally. As I commented under your previous question please provide some context and *tell us why you are interested*, *what you know*, and *what you have found yourself*, see [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [FAQ](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science). Last time Sadeq did it for you but it is your job to provide those information (more)

Comment: You already have a reference that answers your question. If you have read the paper and still don't understand a specific part of it, explain that part and what you have understood and what don't understand. Asking others to explain a whole paper is not a nice practice, (to me) it looks like asking others to do your job. You should try to answer your question by yourself before asking others for help. *Questions should be based on knowledge sharing, not on shirking.* It goes against the spirit of the site.